# Setting the hierachy of multilevel column when pivot_table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The main question is how to set the level order when perform `pivot_table`. The main reason for this as I want to skip the need to rename the columns name when flatten the multilevel columns later.

So, I first create a pivot table as below

```
import pandas as pd


task=['Task',"Task","Task","Task","Task","Task",'Task','Task',"Task","Task","Task","Task","Task",'Task','Task',"Task"]
ba=['SA','SA','SA','SA','SA','SA','SA','SA','SB','SB','SB','SB','SB','SB','SB','SB']
bb=['C1','C1','C2','C2','C1','C1','C2','C2','C1','C1','C2','C2','C1','C1','C2','C2']

nn=['T1','T1','T1','T1','T2','T2','T2','T2','T1','T1','T1','T1','T2','T2','T2','T2']
val=[0.244130039,0.124959401,0.212280307,0.111595529,0.162715589,0.097576324,0.219837052,0.138536738,0.118780642,0.047991315,0.092171826,0.046345554,0.170150394,0.110773621,0.076100716,0.042808913,]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(task,ba,bb,nn,val,val,val)),columns =['mtask', 'sub','task','type','var','var2','var3'])
vars=['var','var2','var3']
idx_label=['mtask', 'sub']
stack_level=['task','type']
df_pv= df.pivot_table(values=vars, index=idx_label, columns=stack_level).reset_index()
print(df_pv)
```

which will produced

```
     mtask sub       var            ...      var3                              
task                  C1            ...        C1                  C2          
type                  T1        T2  ...        T1        T2        T1        T2
0     Task  SA  0.184545  0.130146  ...  0.184545  0.130146  0.161938  0.179187
1     Task  SB  0.083386  0.140462  ...  0.083386  0.140462  0.069259  0.059455
```

But, I want, the column to be in the order of `task`-`type`-`vars` instead of `var`-`task`-`type` as shown above.

This can easily be achieved using transpose and swaplevel as below

```
df_pv= df.pivot_table(values=vars, index=idx_label, columns=stack_level).reset_index().transpose().swaplevel(0, -1).transpose()



type                  T1        T2  ...        T1        T2        T1        T2
task                  C1        C1  ...        C1        C1        C2        C2
     mtask sub       var       var  ...      var3      var3      var3      var3
0     Task  SA  0.184545  0.130146  ...  0.184545  0.130146  0.161938  0.179187
1     Task  SB  0.083386  0.140462  ...  0.083386  0.140462  0.069259  0.059455
```

However, by doing the `transpose` and `swablevel`, flattaning the multilevel columns would required me the rename the `__mtask` and `__sub`

```
df_pv.columns = df_pv.columns.map ( '_'.join )
```

will produced

```
  __mtask __sub T1_C1_var T2_C1_var  ... T1_C1_var3 T2_C1_var3 T1_C2_var3 T2_C2_var3
0    Task    SA  0.184545  0.130146  ...   0.184545   0.130146   0.161938   0.179187
1    Task    SB  0.083386  0.140462  ...   0.083386   0.140462   0.069259   0.059455
```

So, for readability, I had to rename both the `__mtask` and `__sub`

```
df_pv = df_pv.rename(columns={'__mtask': 'mtask','__sub':'sub'})
```

which produced

```
  mtask sub T1_C1_var T2_C1_var  ... T1_C1_var3 T2_C1_var3 T1_C2_var3 T2_C2_var3
0  Task  SA  0.184545  0.130146  ...   0.184545   0.130146   0.161938   0.179187
1  Task  SB  0.083386  0.140462  ...   0.083386   0.140462   0.069259   0.059455
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just fix it with `str.strip`:

```
df_pv.columns = df_pv.columns.map ( '_'.join ).str.strip('_')
```

And now:

```
print(df_pv)
```

Would be:

```
  mtask sub T1_C1_var T2_C1_var  T1_C2_var  T2_C2_var  ... T1_C2_var2 T2_C2_var2 T1_C1_var3 T2_C1_var3 T1_C2_var3 T2_C2_var3
0  Task  SA  0.184545  0.130146   0.161938   0.179187  ...   0.161938   0.179187   0.184545   0.130146   0.161938   0.179187
1  Task  SB  0.083386  0.140462  0.0692587  0.0594548  ...  0.0692587  0.0594548   0.083386   0.140462  0.0692587  0.0594548

[2 rows x 14 columns]
```

The reason this happened is that on the first two multiindex columns they both only had one column instead of 3, so the other ones where empty strings, so they joined with `_`.

Comment: @balandongiv, Why do you think `swap` is required? This already matches the expected output.